make4ht and tabularray error
I get an error when I try to use make4ht with tabularray, here is a MWE :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{l}
    1  \\
    2  \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}

with command line :make4ht test.tex I have this error :
! Undefined control sequence.
\n:__tblr_build_cell_content:NN: ...ll_colspan_tl
                                                  }\xdef \HRowspan {\l__tblr...
l.10 \end
         {tblr}


It seems that some internal macros that Tabularray uses for colspan and rowspan were renamed, but TeX4ht still uses the old names. This version of tabularray.4ht uses the new names and compiles without errors:
% tabularray.4ht (2023-10-25-13:45), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2022-2023 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2023-10-25-13:45}

\NewConfigure{tabularray}{8}
\NewConfigure{tabularrayignoredcell}{2}
\NewConfigure{tabularrayattributes}[1]{\concat:config\CellAttributes{#1\space}}
\NewConfigure{tabularraystyles}[1]{\concat:config\CellStyle{#1}}
\NewConfigure{tabularraycolumnwidth}{1}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewConfigure{tabularrayhalign}[2]{%
  \cs_set:cpn{tabularray_halign:#1}{#2}
}

\NewConfigure{tabularrayvalign}[2]{%
  \cs_set:cpn{tabularray_valign:#1}{#2}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\long\def\:tempa#1#2#3#4{%
  % insert <table>...</table>
  \a:tabularray\o:__tblr_environ_code:nnnn:{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}\b:tabularray
}
\HLet\__tblr_environ_code:nnnn\:tempa

\long\def\:tempa#1{\int_set:Nn \c@rownum {#1}\xdef\HRow{\@arabic\c@rownum}\c:tabularray\o:__tblr_build_row:N:{#1}\d:tabularray}
\HLet\__tblr_build_row:N\:tempa
\ExplSyntaxOff

% disable rules
\ht:special{t4ht@_}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% #1 row number, #2 column, #3 hline number (there can be multiple), #4 css property to be set
\def\:tblr:hlinestyle#1#2#3#4{
  % get line height
  \tl_set:Ne \l__tblr_h_tl{ \__tblr_spec_item:ne { hline } { [#1](#3) / @hline-height } }
  % get dash style
  \def\@tblr@dash{} % remove "dash" word from the variable for correct CSS string
  \tl_set:Ne \l__tblr_f_tl{\__tblr_spec_item:ne { hline } { [#1][#2](#3) / @dash }}
  % create CSS only when a dash style is set
  \tl_if_empty:NF\l__tblr_f_tl{
    % get hline color
    \tl_set:Ne \l__tblr_g_tl { \__tblr_spec_item:ne { hline } { [#1][#2](#3) / fg } }
    \def\:hlinecolor{\#000000}
    % convert color to CSS value if color is set
    \tl_if_empty:NF\l__tblr_g_tl{\get:xcolorcss{\l__tblr_g_tl}\:hlinecolor}
    % \Configure{tabularraystyles} doesn't expand attributes, so we need to expand it here
    % otherwise, we would get wrong color and hline style in the last row, because this macro is called twice here
    \cs_set:ce{#4:}{#4:\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn{\l__tblr_h_tl*2}{1px}px~\l__tblr_f_tl\space~\:hlinecolor;}
    \Configure{tabularraystyles}{\csname#4:\endcsname}
  }
}

\def\:tblr:vlinestyle#1#2#3#4{
  \tl_set:Ne \l__tblr_t_tl{ \__tblr_spec_item:ne { vline } { [#2](#3) / @vline-width } }
  \def\@tblr@dash{} % remove "dash" word from the variable for correct CSS string
  \tl_set:Ne \l__tblr_f_tl{\__tblr_spec_item:ne { vline } { [#1][#2](#3) / @dash }}
  \tl_if_empty:NF\l__tblr_f_tl{
    \tl_set:Ne \l__tblr_g_tl { \__tblr_spec_item:ne { vline } { [#1][#2](#3) / fg } }
    \def\:hlinecolor{\#000000}
    % convert color to CSS value if color is set
    \tl_if_empty:NF\l__tblr_g_tl{\get:xcolorcss{\l__tblr_g_tl}\:hlinecolor}
    % \Configure{tabularraystyles} doesn't expand attributes, so we need to expand it here
    % otherwise, we would get wrong color and hline style in the last row, because this macro is called twice here
    \cs_set:ce{#4:}{#4:\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn{\l__tblr_t_tl*2}{1px}px~\l__tblr_f_tl\space~\:hlinecolor;}
    \Configure{tabularraystyles}{\csname#4:\endcsname}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\long\def\:tempa#1#2{%
% find columns that are covered by rowspan and colspan
  \xdef\HCol{\@arabic\c@colnum}
  \xdef\HRow{\@arabic\c@rownum}
  \xdef\HMultispan{\lTblrCellColSpanTl}
  \xdef\HRowspan{\lTblrCellRowSpanTl}
  \let\CellAttributes\@empty
  \let\CellStyle\@empty
  % calculate ignored cells, if the current cell uses colspan or rowspan
  \int_step_inline:nnn{\c@rownum }{\c@rownum - 1 + \lTblrCellRowSpanTl}{
    \int_step_inline:nnn{\c@colnum }{\c@colnum - 1  + \lTblrCellColSpanTl}{
      % the loop always matches the current cell, we must ignore it
      \str_if_eq:eeF{\HCol.\HRow}{####1.##1}{%
        \cs_gset:cpn{ignoredcell-####1-##1}{}
      }
    }
  }
  \cs_if_exist_use:c{tabularray_halign:\g__tblr_cell_halign_tl}
  \cs_if_exist_use:c{tabularray_valign:\g__tblr_cell_valign_tl}
  % the vertical aligment can be set also in \g__tblr_cell_middle_tl, so we should try it as well
  \cs_if_exist_use:c{tabularray_valign:\g__tblr_cell_middle_tl}
  % calculate column width
  \dim_compare:nNnT {\__tblr_data_item:nen{column}{\HCol}{@col-width}} > {0pt}{
    \__tblr_get_table_width:% initialize \tablewidth
    \edef\HColWidth{\fp_eval:n{\__tblr_data_item:nen{column}{\HCol}{@col-width}/\tablewidth*100}\%}
    % save table width, preferably in CSS
    \a:tabularraycolumnwidth%
  }
  % there can be multiple hlines for each cell, but we only suport the first one, because of limitations of CSS
  \:tblr:hlinestyle{#1}{#2}{1}{border-top}
  \int_compare:nNnT{\HRow + \HRowspan - 1} = {\c@rowcount}{%
    % draw hline below the last row
    \:tblr:hlinestyle{\int_eval:n{\c@rownum + 1}}{#2}{1}{border-bottom}
  }
  % the same is true for vlines
  \:tblr:vlinestyle{#1}{#2}{1}{border-left}
  \int_compare:nNnT{\HCol + \HMultispan - 1} = {\c@colcount}{%
    % draw hline below the last row
    \:tblr:vlinestyle{#1}{\int_eval:n{\c@colnum + 1}}{1}{border-right}
  }
  % support for the background color
  \tl_set:Ne \l__tblr_b_tl
  { \__tblr_data_item:neen { cell } {#1} {#2} { background } }
  % save background color to the list of CSS, if it is set
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l__tblr_b_tl{
    \get:xcolorcss{\l__tblr_b_tl}\:bgcolor
    \Configure{tabularraystyles}{background-color: \:bgcolor;}
  }
  % We can use something like \Configure{tabularrayattributes}{rowspan="\HRowspan"} in \Configure{tabularray}
  % to declare correct attributes for joined cells
  \int_compare:nNnT {\HRowspan} > {1}{\g:tabularray}
  \int_compare:nNnT {\HMultispan} > {1}{\h:tabularray}
  \cs_if_exist:cTF{ignoredcell-\the\c@colnum-\the\c@rownum}{%
    \a:tabularrayignoredcell\e:tabularray\o:__tblr_build_cell_content:NN:{#1}{#2}\f:tabularray\b:tabularrayignoredcell
  }{%
    \e:tabularray\o:__tblr_build_cell_content:NN:{#1}{#2}\f:tabularray
  }
  % the ignored cell is global, so we must undefine it after the thes
  \cs_undefine:c{ignoredcell-\the\c@colnum-\the\c@rownum}%
}
\HLet\__tblr_build_cell_content:NN\:tempa

\ExplSyntaxOff

\Hinput{tabularray}
\endinput


This is the result:
 <table class='tabularray tblr' id='tbl-1'> <tr id='row-1-1-'><td id='cell1-1-1' style='vertical-align:top;'>  1  </td></tr>
 <tr id='row-1-2-'><td id='cell1-2-1' style='vertical-align:top;'>  2  </td></tr></table>


